# embedding python in tcsh

Tags: python, embed, tcsh

So as an example, I know that embedding python in bash as follows work:

```
python -c "import os  
dict_name[\"var1\"]=1  
dict_name[\"var2\"]=2  
"
```

However, when I do the same exact thing in tcsh, I get  the following error:

```
ERROR = Unmatched ".
```

Would anybody happen to have any insight on this? Would I have to `python - c ""` every line?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: here i have an answer, can you try to use this approach  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986354/execute-python-program-from-command-line-without-script-file/50986737#50986737

Comment: thank you for the reply Druta, but I would like to stay in this convention if possible

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
python -c 'import os\
dict_name = {}\
dict_name["var1"]=1\
dict_name["var2"]=2\
'
```

Comment: Hi. While this seems to work, I do not think it is working correctly. For example, let's say that is 1= path to some executable.  the executable should change color within the script, but under this convention, it remains red, making me think the name of the executable is simply a string.

Comment: for example dict_name["EXE"]=$exe_qespresso